# Issus with iOS simulator using MAUI with Visual Studio 2022

Tags: ios, debugging, maui, simulator

I want to debug my application on an iOS simulator
VS is coupled with my mac and I have the latest version of XCode (Version 14.3.1).
I created a simulator on the mac (see screenshot below) :
[image]

In Visual Studio, I find my simulator :
[image]

When I want to debug, I have no issue during the deployment but nothing happend.
No simulator appears in Windows and nothing happens on the mac.

I search everywhere but i found nothing about this issue.
Did I miss a parameter or something else ?

Thank's for your help

Comment: I see that existing questions are about simulator not being listed at all; your situation is unusual. I would use latest VS Mac, create a new Maui project there, get that running on that ios simulator. May have to wait a few minutes the first time; I suspect something internal (between xcode and VS) needs to finish setting up. Then reboot both the Mac and PC. Try again from pc.

Comment: You could install the latest visual studio and also check if XCode can launch simulators successfully.